# Monitor and simulate javascript activity in .NET Webbrowser Control?

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

Traditionally, if one wanted to monitor clicks in IE, you could do it by creating a Browser Helper Object. However, with modern javascript heavy websites (angularjs etc), the traditional click monitoring doesn't work.

Is it possible to monitor javascript clicks in the .NET Webbrowser Control? What if I wanted to simulate a javascript click? Use case is that I have the same site opened on two different .NET Webbrowser controls on two different PCs (both created by me). Lets assume the site is based on angularjs (or some other javascript framework), when the user clicks a link, dropdown etc, on machine A, I want to be able to send a command so that the same action is performed on machine B.